# how to read value of an xml node (single) using linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml structure similar to below one:

```
              <test>
                <test1>test1 value</test1>
               </test>
```

Now I am reading the value of node  using below LINQ to xml code.

```
        var test = from t in doc.Descendants("test") select t.Element("test1").Value;
        Console.WriteLine("print single node value");
        foreach (var item in test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);   
        }
```

above code works fine, but here I have one single node, but to retrive value I am using foreach loop, which I dont think is good..any better way of doing the same thing without a foreach loop
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String xml = @"<test>
                <test1>test1 value</test1>
                        </test>";

        var test = XElement.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants("test1")
                .First()
                .Value;

        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will/ is working , but i am reading the values from a xml file.

Comment: @Wondering - Then all you need to do is change `XElement.Parse(xml)` to `XElement.Load(pathToYourFile)`.

Comment: ok, as per my code, i changed it to   var res = doc.Descendants("test1").First().Value;  and it worked.thanks for all ur help

Answer (score 0):

you can also try providing XML file path like following:

```
 XElement xmldoc = XElement.Load("filePath");
        var nodeValueFromXMlFile = xmldoc
             .Descendants("node name")
             .First()
             .Value;
        System.Console.WriteLine(nodeValueFromXMlFile);
```